# VBNET How to insert multiple selected checkbox into sql database

Tags: vb.net

I've an ADD Button which will save all the records into the vb database. 
But, I can't figure out how to select multiple checkbox and insert them into one column.

Example Table:

```
Drinks Attributes

[] Coke
[X] Sprite
[] Pepsi
[X] 100 Plus
[X] Orange Juice
```

```
 Private Sub btnSAVE_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSAVE.Click

            cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Restaurant (DrinksID, Drinks, Amount) Values (@DrinksID, @Drinks, @Amount);", con)

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@DrinksID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 5).Value = txtPatientID.Text
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Drinks", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value =
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Amount", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30).Value = chkConsultation.Text
            End With
```

And Also, I wanted the users to checked first `cmd.Parameters.Add("@Amount", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30).Value = chkConsultation.Text`, then only insert the checkbox text. 
But, I've no idea how does it works.

Comment: Storing multiple values in a column in a table in a relational database is a sign of poor database design. Each column should hold only one value.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your kind reply. Mind if I ask, what suggestion you'll be giving me to solve my issues? Much appreciated

Comment: You should consider normalizing that table to first normal form. That will result in an additional table where you can store those multiple values as multiple rows. Then every aspect of working with that data will become much more straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep your database objects local so you can be sure they are closed and disposed with `Using...End Using` blocks.

I would increase the size of the Drinks field in the database. You are getting close to 50.

To get a value for Drinks create an array of the check boxes. Build a list of strings with the `.Text` property of each checked `CheckBox`. Finally, join the strings with `String.Join`.

```
Private Sub btnSAVE_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSAVE.Click
    Dim checks = {CheckBox1, CheckBox2, CheckBox3}
    Dim drinks As New List(Of String)
    For Each box In checks
        If box.Checked Then
            drinks.Add(box.Text)
        End If
    Next
    Dim paramValueDrinks = String.Join(",", drinks.ToArray)
    Using con As New SqlConnection("Your connection sting"),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Restaurant (DrinksID, Drinks, Amount) Values (@DrinksID, @Drinks, @Amount);", con)
        With cmd.Parameters
            .Add("@DrinksID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 5).Value = txtPatientID.Text
            .Add("@Drinks", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = paramValueDrinks
            .Add("@Amount", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30).Value = chkConsultation.Text
        End With
    End Using
End Sub
```

@ Honeyboy Wilson is correct. Multiple values in a field violates Normal Form. If you want to correct your database a second table with the primary key from this table and the drink should do it.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot and it seems working well. But I would like to ask if I make another table for drinks. How am i going to code them? like inserting each data to each field. Much appreciated if you could  help out

Comment: Making the new table would further normalize your database. It depends on how far you want to go with this application. We would need to get into the concepts of Primary Key and Foreign Key. Which is beyond the scope of this question.